# How can I listen for two key press event at a same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Below code works perfectly fine but I'm trying to achieve here is that I want to listen for `ctrl + b` key and Output some value according to it.

```
  document.addEventListener( 'keydown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.code === 'ControlLeft') {
      console.log('CTRL Left Pressed')
    }
});
```

I've tried `&&` operator in below example but it's not working for me.

```
  document.addEventListener( 'keydown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.code === 'ControlLeft' && event.code === 'KeyB') {
      console.log('CTRL Left and b Pressed')
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) property. `event.code` obviously cannot be equal to two different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey

The KeyboardEvent comes with a `ctrlKey` property especially for these kinds of uses.

Your code would then become;

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( event.code === 'KeyB' && event.ctrlKey === true ) {
      console.log('CTRL Left and b Pressed')
    }
});
```

Comment: As you can see on the provided page, there are also properties for the alt and shift key, in case you were to ever need to check for those combinations in the future. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if( true === event.ctrlKey && 'b' === event.key ) 
    console.log('CTRL+B Combination true!')
});
```

```html
Press CTRL+B Combination.
```